# How to maintain a latex table easily?

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, longtable

I have a huge latex table and sometimes I need to update fields, delete a row, insert a new column ... In Microsoft Word I can do it pretty easy, but with Latex it is getting pretty complicated and cost me a lot of time. 
For example if I have a table of 100 rows. If I want to insert a new column and want to insert 4 Values and the rest 96 should be empty. At the moment I have to  update every row in latex.
I am wondering if there is maybe an easier/faster way. I know that there are some Online Tools that help me to create a Latex table. For example if you google "latex table generator". But is there any Tool, Software, Function... that helps me to maintain my latex table?
Thank you for your support!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Texstudio quite a lot of options for such manipulations: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ka25c.png

Comment: It would depend on what kind of editing environment you are using when writing your LaTeX file, right? For example I'm using AucTeX in Emacs. If I wanted to add a new column somewhere in the middle of a long table I would use a keyboard macro in Emacs to do that. But an answer about how to do that wouldn't help if you don't use Emacs.

Comment: @pst Which kbd-macro in AucTeX? Just if I needed it some day... Besides this: Maybe folks should learn the basics about LaTeX first, before they deliberately tackle a beast like Emacs?

Comment: @KeksDose I have not recommended any particular editor here, or assumed anything about what P-ziggy36 uses or doesn't use. Only made the point that to answer this question one would need to know what editing environment it is about.

Comment: Hey, I am using the Notepad. Is it also possible with Notepad?

Comment: I haven't used it, but as far as I know Notepad doesn't really have fancy features, so I don't think you can get much help from it in doing this. Then maybe it's easiest to have the table data separate in some way (as Keks Dose's answer suggests).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got a *.tex file including a huge tabular and now you'd like to change it. So your question isn't exactly about LaTeX, but about the way and the tools to maintain *.tex files.

A *.tex file will be opened in an »editor«. There a many different editors out there and some of them offer some kind of tools to insert new columns, e.g. TeXStudio.

*But however, to me this seems the wrong way.* A text file isn't the right place to develop huge tables.

The easiest way is to develop and maintain the tabular in LibreOffice Calc or in Microsoft Excel and to transfer it shortly before finishing the document into the *.tex file. The way to do this depends on the kind of tabular, but we have had many questions here about calc2latex and excel2latex (the latter has got its own tag!).

So where does your tabular come from? Is there an original dwelling somewhere and you can go back? Or will it be necessary and worth time and effort to transfer your LaTeX tabular into an *.odt or *.xls file? Probably not an issue, because importing a LaTeX tabular into a spreadsheet usually is easy: the "&"-sign separates the cells.